# Common table expression incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to execute this CTE but it says there is a syntax error that I am not able to find.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Could anybody please spot something that I am unable to?

```
    ;with sqltmp  (   
     eohdr_ouinstance, eohdr_eo_no,   eohdr_rev_no,  
     eohdr_engdoctype, eohdr_src_doc_type,  eohdr_mcm_no,  
     eoae_ac_reg_no,  eoae_applicability_grp, eopse_part_no,  
     eopse_serial_no, eopse_component_id,  maint_obj,  
     maint_obj_type,  trans_status,   pre_comp_date,  
     jobtype,   exec_doc_no)  
   AS (  
   SELECT eohdr_ouinstance, eohdr_eo_no,   eohdr_rev_no,  
     eohdr_engdoctype, eohdr_src_doc_type,  eohdr_mcm_no,  
     eoae_ac_reg_no,  eoae_applicability_grp, NULL,   
     NULL,    NULL,     eoae_ac_reg_no,  
     'A',    eoae_applicable,  eoae_precompdate,  
     'AC',    eoae_precompdoc  
   FROM eo_eohdr_eo_header  WITHa (NOLOCK)  
   JOIN eo_eoae_eo_ac_effect  WITH (NOLOCK)     
   ON  eohdr_ouinstance    = eoae_ouinstance  
   AND  eohdr_eo_no      = eoae_eo_no  
   AND  eohdr_rev_no     = eoae_rev_no  
   AND  eoae_applicable     IN  ('N', 'PCW')  
   AND  ISNULL(eohdr_cr_no, '##')  =  '##'  
     
   UNION  
   SELECT eohdr_ouinstance,  eohdr_eo_no,    eohdr_rev_no,  
     eohdr_engdoctype,  eohdr_src_doc_type,   eohdr_mcm_no,  
     NULL,     eopse_applicability_grp, eopse_part_no,  
     eopse_serial_no,  eopse_component_id,   eopse_component_id,  
     'C',     eopse_applicable,   eopse_precompdate,  
     CASE WHEN eohdr_instiu_flag = 'Y' THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFWG' END,  
     eopse_precompdoc  
   FROM eo_eohdr_eo_header  WITH (NOLOCK)  
   JOIN eo_eopse_eo_part_serial_effect  WITH (NOLOCK)    
   ON  eohdr_ouinstance    = eopse_ouinstance  
   AND  eohdr_eo_no      = eopse_eo_no  
   AND  eohdr_rev_no     = eopse_rev_no  
   AND  eopse_applicable    IN  ('N', 'PCW')  
   AND  ISNULL(eohdr_cr_no,'##')  =  '##')
```

Comment: You need to share the error message you received. It tells you where the error is along with the line number.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

This is the message but I haven't missed out anything to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: is that "FROM eo_eohdr_eo_header  WITHa (NOLOCK) ", the "a" after the WITH, normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax appears to be fine. When you add a SELECT after the cte definition, it parses fine:

```
 ;with sqltmp  (   
     eohdr_ouinstance, eohdr_eo_no,   eohdr_rev_no,  
     eohdr_engdoctype, eohdr_src_doc_type,  eohdr_mcm_no,  
     eoae_ac_reg_no,  eoae_applicability_grp, eopse_part_no,  
     eopse_serial_no, eopse_component_id,  maint_obj,  
     maint_obj_type,  trans_status,   pre_comp_date,  
     jobtype,   exec_doc_no)  
   AS (  
   SELECT eohdr_ouinstance, eohdr_eo_no,   eohdr_rev_no,  
     eohdr_engdoctype, eohdr_src_doc_type,  eohdr_mcm_no,  
     eoae_ac_reg_no,  eoae_applicability_grp, NULL,   
     NULL,    NULL,     eoae_ac_reg_no,  
     'A',    eoae_applicable,  eoae_precompdate,  
     'AC',    eoae_precompdoc  
   FROM eo_eohdr_eo_header  WITHa (NOLOCK)  
   JOIN eo_eoae_eo_ac_effect  WITH (NOLOCK)     
   ON  eohdr_ouinstance    = eoae_ouinstance  
   AND  eohdr_eo_no      = eoae_eo_no  
   AND  eohdr_rev_no     = eoae_rev_no  
   AND  eoae_applicable     IN  ('N', 'PCW')  
   AND  ISNULL(eohdr_cr_no, '##')  =  '##'  
     
   UNION  



   SELECT eohdr_ouinstance,  eohdr_eo_no,    eohdr_rev_no,  
     eohdr_engdoctype,  eohdr_src_doc_type,   eohdr_mcm_no,  
     NULL,     eopse_applicability_grp, eopse_part_no,  
     eopse_serial_no,  eopse_component_id,   eopse_component_id,  
     'C',     eopse_applicable,   eopse_precompdate,  
     CASE WHEN eohdr_instiu_flag = 'Y' THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFWG' END,  
     eopse_precompdoc  
   FROM eo_eohdr_eo_header  WITH (NOLOCK)  
   JOIN eo_eopse_eo_part_serial_effect  WITH (NOLOCK)    
   ON  eohdr_ouinstance    = eopse_ouinstance  
   AND  eohdr_eo_no      = eopse_eo_no  
   AND  eohdr_rev_no     = eopse_rev_no  
   AND  eopse_applicable    IN  ('N', 'PCW')  
   AND  ISNULL(eohdr_cr_no,'##')  =  '##'
   )  

   SELECT 1
   from sqltmp
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. May I know what the reason is? Why is it expecting us to add that line there despite the syntax being correct?

Comment: Not 100% sure as to the why, but when you declare a CTE, you need a SELECT after it in order for it to be valid, and you also have to query using the CTE for it to be valid. For example, change `SELECT 1 FROM sqltmp` to `SELECT 1` and it will error.

Comment: Thank you so much!